30mA load requirement for power supply
Can someone tell me how to implement a 1.2V to 80V, active 30mA load circuit for the out-put of a power supply. This circuit would be integrated into the PWBA.
I’m using a TL783 regulator with four by-pass transistors that will conduct 2 to 4 amps.
This by-pass arrangement requires a 30mA load to operate correctly.
I have tried constant current mirror (matched betas),………………. To no avail.
Any circuit ideas are welcome.
See circuit schematic below


That is one busy circuit...

Yes it is, and even more!

Is 1.2-80 V the input or output voltage range? If yes, what’s the input?

Lots of questions here- Input voltage range as @winny said, output ripple spec, any load transient requirements, accuracy requirements, efficiency target, protection features, safety and isolation requirement, etc.  Looks like you want a linear operating from a bridge rectifier, but depending on your requirements there may be better/different ways to go.

R17 in the schematic is mislabeled, it was intended to be used as a 30mA load. But it did not fair well over the voltage range (1.2V-75V); dynamically the current it changed over the voltage range. I’m simply looking for an active 30mA load that will work over the voltage range (1.2V-75V) of the output. I’m not planning to sale this PS, just using it as a lab supply for experiments.
My requirement:
75V @1A, 25V to 50V @ 2A.
I’m satisfied with the ripple & noise.
Short-circuit works very well.
Voltages are tap switched to hold the TL783’s Vdiff at 20V or > 25 V.

Wilson current source (or sink, in your case) should work here.  The trick is finding a good BJT that can handle the high-ish voltage and peak power (75V x 30mA = 2.25W).  Adding an op-amp to a Wilson would improve output impedance, particularly at the low voltage end (1.2V).

I’ve had a bit of a problem with this circuit in the past; matching transistors (Beta’s, & others things), especially Thermo-run-away issues.
So how would you go about doing this. Can you show me this in a schematic?
Also where do you get an 80V or more Op-Amp (cheap), or does one use a divider network on the Op-Amp to lower the voltage?
